# erorr dump apache pig

Tags: apache-pig, dump

I load 1 data from hdfs:demo2.txt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3ohN.png)
command:data = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:9000/demo1/demo2.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray, age:int, city:chararray);
then I DUMP data;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30f2a.png)

it stops at 0% complete and doesn't run anymore
Please help me correct this error

I want to know what the error is and how to fix it